# Confusion about complexity of two dependent loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for(i=1; i < n; i++){
   for(j=1; j <= i; j++){
         statement1;
   }       
}
```

- outer loop = O(N)
- Inner loop = N(N-1)/2
- Total = N*N(N-1)/2 = N^3

it seems n^3 is complexity of these nested loops. but accordings to books, its complexity is n^2 from N(N-1)/2 .

Comment: If we had a penny for everytime this *exact* question has been asked....

Comment: outler loop = O(N), inner loop = O((N-1)/2) = O(N), Total = O(N*N)

Comment: inner loop O((N-1)/2) How? i am unable to understand this?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the inner loop was `N(N-1)/2`?

Comment: Because , Inner loop behaviour is like. 0+1+2+3+4+...+N-1, 
that is same to mathematical series formula N(N-1)/2 .

Comment: You have answered your own question there - this sum already takes into account the executions of the outer loop. It makes no sense to then multiply it by N

Comment: yes, this seems answer to my question.

Comment: but it is confusing if i see two nested loops. where inner is is same like this, or outter is like (int i=0; i<N; i = i*2) , Now how to count complexity?

Comment: That should be another question. There are countless many questions about this form of loop too. I suggest you do a quick search before posting again.

Comment: I was expecting answer from you.

Comment: You should make an effort to find out for yourself before you ask us - and that includes searching for existing SO posts.

Comment: I don't see the question being closed as duplicate though. I did a quick search right now and it seems that most questions with such a topic are very specific loops, different to this one. So it seems to be a question that is not easily found by a quick search. The topic is frequent, but that specific scenario not. So as long as there don't appear dup votes and casts, it is fine in my opinion and we should suppose that OP did search (if not, please don't forget).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only interesting thing to count is how often `statement1` will be executed.

Therefore, note that something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        statement1;
```

triggers `2 * 3 = 6` executions. So you count how often the inner loop gets executed **per outer loop iteration**.

However, in your example you did a mistake and multiplied the iterations of the outer loop with the **total iterations** of the inner loop, not the number of iterations **per outer loop iteration**.

In the example above that would be like `2 * 6 = 12` instead of only `2 * 3 = 6`.

---

Let's take a closer look at what happens in your specific example. The outer loop triggers `n` iterations of the inner loop. The inner loop first yields `1` iteration. In the next iteration of the outer loop it will yield `2` iterations, then `3` and so on.

In total you will thus receive `1 + 2 + ... + n = (n^2 - n)/2` iterations of the inner loop. Again, note the '**in total**'. So `statement1` will **in total** be executed `(n^2 - n)/2` times. The outer loops iterations are already taken into account for the computation of the inner loops total runs, no additional multiplication.

---

`(n^2 - n)/2` is obviously in `O(n^2)` due to its asymptotic complexity. Intuitively only the biggest factor plays a role, we can drop other stuff by estimating with `<=`.

```
(n^2 - n)/2
    <= n^2 - n
    <= n^2 in O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. for(i=1; i < n; i++){
2. for(j=1; j <= i; j++){
3. statement1;
4. }
5. }

In order to simplify the problem, let's assume that n is 5 here.
So line 1 will execute 5 times since it will check and increment i value 5 times.
line 2 will execute (5-1)=4 times because for i=5, it will not execute but line 1 will execute for i=5.
line 3 will execute for 1 time, 2 times 3 times and so on, each time i is incremented.

Take complexity of 3rd line into context and you'll find that it is executing 1+2+3+4=10  times. It's simply the sum of numbers from 1 to 4 or you can say, n(n+1)/2 where n=4.
We can ignore the complexity of line 1 and line 2 since they are constant and in asymptotic notation , the complexity will be O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

You can think about the 2 nested loops as checking all the cells on the diagonal and below the diagonal on a N x N matrix.

So you'll always do a number of operations close to 1/2 of N^2. So the total number of operations of your code will be N^2 * constant. By the definition of Big-O notation, that means that your code runtime complexity is O(n^2).

Here is a simple code to help you understand my explanation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// These function count the number of times that your code will execute statement1
int count(int N){
    int total = 0;
    for(int l = 0; l < N; ++l){
        for(int r = 0; r <= l; ++r){
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

// this code will show the cells of the matrix that you are "executing"
int showMatrix(int N){
    vector<vector<bool> > mat(N, vector<bool>(N, false) );
    for(int l = 0; l < N; ++l){
        for(int r = 0; r <= l; ++r){
            mat[l][r] = true;
        }
    }

    for(int line = 0; line < N; ++line){
        for(int column = 0; column < N; ++column){
            cout << (mat[line][column] == true ? "1 " : "0 ");
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    showMatrix(10);
    cout << count(10) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```